# Higher categories using just simplicial sets

Tags: higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

Is there a definition of $(\infty, n)$-category using just simplicial sets?

This is the case for $n \leq 2$.

Is the forgetful functor from saturated $n$-trivial complicial sets to simplicial sets an embedding of 1-categories?

Comment: Wait, Is it true for $n=2$?

Comment: @SimonHenry First question: yes (see https://kerodon.net/tag/01W9)
Second question: I don't know.

Comment: Interesting! In any case, it is known that Street Nerve (from strict infinity category to simplicial sets) is not fuly faitfull (but it become fuly faithfull when viewed as valued in complicial sets with the appropriate notion of thiness. I don't quite remember what is the counter-exemple, but I'd expect it would provide also a negative answer to your question... So the answer might be in old paper of Street and/or Roberts... but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: I don't know what's the current status of the theory, but didn't Riehl's complicial sets project precisely model (oo,n)-categories as simplicial sets with structure?